# .net core authorize Roles do not use magic string

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, authorize-attribute, magic-string

it's my code. but not work

```
[Authorize(Roles = nameof(SD.ROLE_ADMIN))]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserAsync([FromBody] ManagementUserRequestDTO requestDTO)
    {
        var responseDTO = await _accountRepository.DeleteUser(requestDTO);

        if (responseDTO.IsSucceeded)
            return Ok(responseDTO);

        return BadRequest(responseDTO);
    }
```

if change [Authorize(Roles = nameof(SD.ROLE_ADMIN))]  to
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")] it work correctly

SD.ROLE_Admin -----> public static string ROLE_ADMIN {get; set;} = "admin"  at static class

how to fix it? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nameof(SD.ROLE_ADMIN)` equals **"ROLE_ADMIN"** and your Role's name is **"admin"**, it should be enough if you change to `[Authorize(Roles = SD.ROLE_ADMIN)]`

And you need to change `public static string ROLE_ADMIN {get; set;} = "admin"` to `public const string ROLE_ADMIN = "admin"`. It needs to be a constant expression.

Comment: it not work. [Authorize(Roles = SD.ROLE_ADMIN)]   show warnning CS0182:
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

so I added nameof

Comment: @otterotter Updated the answer , you can change static string to const string.